# Why does numpy import behave differently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pip

I used the following commands to install numpy in my python3 virtual environment on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS machine.

My goal is to use python 3.5 by default in my venv and learn numpy. I shouldn't have to explicitly use `python3`. I feel there's some overlap/error which could be a bigger issue if ignored now.
Also, I don't have python 2.x installed in my virtual environment but I have it at system level.

The commands `python3 -V` and `python -V` show the same version and both are located at same path. Why does the last command work but the second to last doesn't work?

```
~/proj1$ virtualenv --no-site-packages -p python3 venv
Already using interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/$USER/proj1/venv/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /home/$USER/proj1/venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...done.
~/proj1$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) ~/proj1$ which pip
/home/$USER/proj1/venv/bin/pip
(venv) ~/proj1$ pip -V
pip 20.0.2 from /home/$USER/proj1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)
(venv) ~/proj1$ pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.18.1-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (19.9 MB)
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.18.1
(venv) ~/proj1$ python -V
Python 3.5.2
(venv) ~/proj1$ python3 -V
Python 3.5.2
(venv) ~/proj1$ which python
/home/$USER/proj1/venv/bin/python
(venv) ~/proj1$ which python3
/home/$USER/proj1/venv/bin/python3
(venv) ~/proj1$ python -c "import numpy"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
(venv) ~/proj1$ python3 -c "import numpy"
(venv) ~/proj1$
```

Comment: What happens if you run `/home/$USER/proj1/venv/bin/python -c "import numpy"` (making sure you've typed the full path to `python`)?

Comment: Also, what happens if you run "`alias | grep -i python`" (without the quotes)?

Comment: What’s `sys.path` in each case?

Comment: @jjramsey running python with full path works fine. Running alias like you mentioned prints `alias python='/usr/bin/python3' `

Comment: @DavisHerring I'm guessing by each case you mean, with and without venv activated. It is the same in both cases. Here's the output:
`['/home/$USER/proj1', '/usr/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/home/$USER/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']`

Comment: @keyur: Thanks, but the other case I meant was `python` *vs.* `python3` as the command (as affects your result).

Comment: @DavisHerring Got it. The above result was using `python`. Here's the output using `python3`
`['/home/$USER/proj1', '/home/$USER/proj1/venv/lib/python35.zip', '/home/$USER/proj1/venv/lib/python3.5', '/home/$USER/proj1/venv/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/home/$USER/proj1/venv/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/home/$USER/proj1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages']`

Comment: Was it you who created the `python='/usr/bin/python3'` alias?

Comment: Never use the `pip` script directly, instead always use its executable module explicitly `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip somecommand` -- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with `numpy` per se. Rather, what's happening is that the alias `python='/usr/bin/python3'` prevents your shell from finding the `python` executable that's first in your execution path (i.e., the executable with the path given by "`which python`"), which messes with your virtual environment setup. Because of that alias,

```sh
python -c "import numpy"
```

is interpreted as

```sh
/usr/bin/python3 -c "import numpy"
```

Since you installed `numpy` in a virtual environment, the system-wide Python 3 installation in `/usr/bin` has *by design* no knowledge of that `numpy` installation, so you get that `ImportError`.

If, on the other hand, you were to run

```sh
unalias python
python -c "import numpy"
```

then `python` would be taken to be `/home/$USER/proj1/venv/bin/python`, provided that you had already sourced `/home/$USER/proj1/venv/bin/activate`, of course, and things would work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It makes sense how this could be the issue. I can't get to the system right now where I saw this error. As soon as I'm able to, I will test this and post the result.

Comment: I'm sorry for responding so late but this is indeed the scenario. Thanks @jjramsey!

Answer (score -1):

The moral here is “don’t use `which`”.  `bash` (which almost everyone uses now) has a builtin command `type` that shows how a command is interpreted; in particular, `type -a python` here would show you that it *would* be your virtual environment’s `python`, but is in fact **aliased** to run the one from `/usr/bin` that is the same version but doesn’t have the same packages installed (because of course the virtual environment’s directories aren’t on its `sys.path`).

Comment: Nothing wrong with `which`. The real moral here is really to not use an alias to work around the executable path.

Comment: @jjramsey: `which`, as an external command, is never able to give truly accurate information, which is inexcusable in a diagnostic tool for situations like this.  Some versions even try to pipe `alias` through `grep` to augment its `PATH` search, which is a bit ridiculous.  Certainly it is **also** true that aliases must be used with caution and understanding.